# Maps ConfigurationSection directly to the correct type

Tags: c#, configuration

I'm writing my own custom HttpModule that provides some error logging which a logging module which I've written.

Now, in the .NET framework, in the web.config, you encounter a lot of thoses situations:

```
<add name="myName" type="myType, MyAssembly" />.
```

I now have created my custom configuration section that looks as:

```
public class ErrorHandlingConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("BackingStoreProvider", DefaultValue = "In-Memory", IsRequired = true)]
    public string BackingStoreProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)this["BackingStoreProvider"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["BackingStoreProvider"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I'm passing a string in here. But it it possible to change this to pass a type (still a string) and that my custom configuration section will map it directly to the type and thrown an error if the type, assembly or anything else could not be found?

I tought that something like this would be possible:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("BackingStoreProvider", IsRequired = true)]
public IBackingStore BackingStoreProvider
{
    get
    {
        var type = this["BackingStoreProvider"].ToString().Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

        IBackingStore backingStore = (IBackingStore)Activator.CreateInstance(type[1], type[0]);

        return backingStore;
    }
}
```

But off course an exception is thrown then:

```
An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in     System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The value of the property 'BackingStoreProvider' cannot be     parsed. The error is: Unable to find a converter that supports conversion to/from string      for the property 'BackingStoreProvider' of type 'IBackingStore'.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok guys,

I'm sorry but I've actually found the answer on stackoverflow already.

If anyone's intrested, this is the code that should be used:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TypeNameConverter))]
[ConfigurationProperty("BackingStoreProvider", IsRequired = true)]
public IBackingStore BackingStoreProvider
{
    get
    {
        var type = this["BackingStoreProvider"].ToString().Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

        IBackingStore backingStore = (IBackingStore) Activator.CreateInstance(this["BackingStoreProvider"] as Type);

        return backingStore;
    }
}
```